# How to remove a specified string from a string

Tags: java, string, replace, delimiter

Ok so I'm trying to create a method that takes 2 strings, the second string argument is the string to be removed from the first string argument. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code? Any help? Thanks.

Example of what I'm trying to do: if you pass in "a,b,c" as the first argument and "," as the second argument, you get "abc" returned.

```
public List<String> split(String string, String delimiter){
    //create and init arraylist.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create and init newString.
    String newString="";
    //add string to arraylist 'list'.
    list.add(string);
    //loops through string.
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        //stores each character from string in newString.
        newString += string.charAt(i);

        }
    newString.replace(delimiter, "");
    //remove string from arraylist 'list'.
    list.remove(string);
    //add newString to arraylist 'list'.
        list.add(newString);


    return list;
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate what language this is.

Comment: Have you looked into `String.split` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: If `a,b,c` is a string and you want string `abc`, why cann't you just do `yourString.replaceAll(secondArg, "");`

Comment: why is the  return type a `List`, shouldn't it be a `String`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, not sure what you're doing with those lists, but based on your worded question, if all you want is `abc` from `a,b,c`, this will do it...

```
 public String split(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.replace(s2,"");
 }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I have in comment.....I did not post an answer because this returns `string` and the question has `List`

Comment: I felt the OP's use of lists was overkill and unnecessary when `replace()` achieves the same result with far less code. Don't be afraid to improve the OP's solution if you feel it can help, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by method name, return type and parameter names, it seems like you're attempting to reinvent the wheel - you only need one line:

```
public List<String> split(String string, String delimiter){
    return Arrays.asList(string.split("\\" + delimiter));
}
```

I put the backslash in there in case the delimiter itself is a regex, like a dot.

Comment: Those loops took me for a loop, glad I wasn't the only one :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> split(String str, String delimiter){
    //Is the List of strings mandatory? Or is it part of a solution
    //that didn't originally have to be so?

    String[] temp;
    List<String> newStrings=new ArrayList<String>(); 

    //The answer was split(String regex) all along!
    temp = str.split(delimiter);

    for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
        newStrings.add(temp[i]);
    }

    return newStrings;
}
```

}

This will produce the desired specifications you have, but be warned that this will include spaces as individual strings. I will update this if you request it exclude spaces.